# Selecting Substring SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, substring

I need to select a substring that is found between (). The starting and ending position will vary, as well as the length of the substring. I have had moderate success with the following but not 100%.

It will work for some values but not for others, it return blanks and will also change the values capitalization format, in other words if value is 'TEST' it will display as 'Test'.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(columnName, CHARINDEX('(', LEN(columnName)),
CHARINDEX(')', columnName) - CHARINDEX('(',columnName)) AS INPUT
FROM tableName
```

*Update* There is only 1 set of parentheses ()

Comment: There's no way that query will change the case of the substring, can you provide an example?

Comment: So can you clarify - what problem have you faced with your query? And how is it concerned to character case changing?

Comment: The character case is the least of my concerns. My biggest concern is that this query will select the correct substring between () for some values but for other it will completely miss.

Comment: What 'others'? Provide examples of what it's missing. The more we guess, the more chance we'll get it wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work provided you only have a single occurence of `(` and `)`:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(columnName, 
              CHARINDEX('(', columnName)+1, 
              CHARINDEX(')', columnName) - CHARINDEX('(', columnName)-1)
FROM tableName
```

If you have values that do not have any `(...)` content, add this where clause:

```
WHERE    CHARINDEX('(', columnName) > 0 AND 
         CHARINDEX(')', columnName) > CHARINDEX('(', columnName)
```

Comment: This query gives me the following error:
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Then not all your data has a `(....)` value. I've added a `WHERE` clause to cope with that.

Answer (score 2):

To account for no, nested or incomplete `()`

```
;with t(f) as (
    select 'aaa(bbb)ccc' union
    select 'aaa(bbbccc' union
    select 'aaabbb)ccc' union
    select 'aaa()ccc' union
    select '(aaa(?))ccc'
)

select f,
case when patindex('%(%)%', f) > 0 
    then substring(f, charindex('(', f ) + 1, (len(f) - charindex(')', reverse(f))) - charindex('(', f )) 
    else ''
end
from t

>>

f             (No column name)
aaa()ccc    
aaa(bbb)ccc   bbb
(aaa(?))ccc   aaa(?)
aaa(bbbccc  
aaabbb)ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, you can do this using POSIX regular expression capture:

```
=> select substring('This (might) work' from '[(](.*)[)]');
 substring 
-----------
 might
```

It appears SQL server does offer [regexp support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx#S3), but I'm not familiar with it and I don't have a platform to run a test case.  This particular example is tricky because you have to get the quoting of the delimiters `()` right.

Comment: Not sure this is an answer, there's nothing like that in SQL Server!

Comment: REGEX is only available when using a CLR based proc (i.e. a stored proc written in, for example, C#), not something I would recommend in this case.